# Redirected page isn't rendering after submitting modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I use such views for handling modal windows with form.You can check detailed explanation of this approach here https://dmorgan.info/posts/django-views-bootstrap-modals/
Everything works fine, but submitted data doesn't appear in my_orders view after redirecting to this view.
I see GET request to /my_orders/ in Chrome console. And response contains submitted data. But seems that this response doesn't render in my view. Maybe, It's caused by XHR response?

At the same time redirect works fine in this method, and after redirecting I've got actual my_orders view.

```
def delete_order(request, id):
     Order.objects.filter(id = id).delete()
     return redirect('currency_exchange.views.my_orders')
```

**views.py**

```
def my_orders(request):
    queryset = Order.objects.filter(user=get_user(request))
    context = {
            "queryset": queryset
        }
    return render(request, "my_orders.html", context)

class AjaxTemplateMixin(object):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(self, 'ajax_template_name'):
            split = self.template_name.split('.html')
            split[-1] = '_inner'
            split.append('.html')
            self.ajax_template_name = ''.join(split)
        if request.is_ajax():
            self.template_name = self.ajax_template_name
        return super(AjaxTemplateMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

class AddOrderView(SuccessMessageMixin, AjaxTemplateMixin, FormView, CreateView):
     model = Order
     template_name = 'add_order_form.html'
     form_class = OrderForm
     success_url = reverse_lazy('my_orders')
     success_message = "Way to go!"

     def form_valid(self, form):
        order = form.save(commit=False)
        order.user = self.request.user
        order.save()
        return redirect('currency_exchange.views.my_orders')
```

**JS:**

```
var formAjaxSubmit = function(form, modal) {
                $(form).submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: $(this).attr('method'),
                        url: $(this).attr('action'),
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            if ( $(xhr).find('.has-error').length > 0 ) {
                                $(modal).find('.modal-body').html(xhr);
                                formAjaxSubmit(form, modal);
                            } else {
                                $(modal).modal('toggle');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show your JS. But if you are sending an Ajax request, you need to do something in the JS code to actually do the redirect.

Comment: Add JS to the question

Comment: OK. So where in that JS code is the thing that changes the URL?

Comment: Thing that changes the URL is in python code: `return redirect('currency_exchange.views.my_orders')`. At least It works In case of `def delete_order()`

Comment: Yes I saw that, but this is an Ajax request so the browser is not handling it directly. You need to write some JS code to do anything at all: in the same way as you wrote some JS to display the errors rather than them just appearing on the page, you need to write some JS to change the URL.

Comment: You are right. I don't know what approach is the best, but this `window.location.replace('url');` works for me